# Server communication of RSA new pin mode using RADIUS

Tags: java, security, authentication, rsa, radius

I'm implementing RADIUS authentication procedure on a client in a java application.

The RADIUS Server uses [RSA SecurID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID) to authenticate the users. As known [RSA SecurID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID) uses a token. When a user forgets his pin for the token, the token can be set to a special new pin mode on the server which forces the user to set a new pin on the next login attempt.

As fas as I know the communication workflow with the server would look like the following:

1. Client: Send Access-Request Package to the Server with the usual attributes.
2. Server: Reply with a package indicating the special new pin mode
3. Client: Display an Interface to the user to enter a new pin. Send a package to the server containing the new pin.
4. Server: Reply with a Package saying that the pin has been successfully set.
5. Client: Display a confirmation message and ask the user for a new passcode which he created using the new pin on his token. I assume this is basically the same package as in step 1.
6. Server: Reply with an Access-Accept package if OK or and Access-Reject if Not-OK

For step 2, 3, 4 and 5 I do not know how the package structure looks like and therefore cannot implement any logic on the client. Has anyone knowledge about the Server communication with a token is in new pin mode?

Cheers
Simon

The tokens used look like this. To create a valid passcode you need to first type your PIN and hit the diamond key below the 7:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [comprosec.ch](http://www.comprosec.ch/fileadmin/images/rsa/securid/SD520_450x297_72dpi_crop.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Are you talking about the RSA [SecurID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID) token product?  The term "RSA" by itself usually refers to the [cipher algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to look at the 'Reply-Message' (Type 18) attribute sent within the RADIUS packet from the server. It's very hacky, but it's the official solution since the RADIUS protocol doesn't support such states (see [RFC 2865](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2865.txt)). Talk to your RSA contact, they can provide you with a test server and 2 test tokens to test your parsing code.

Here is what I have found out so far:

- New-PIN-mode entry

Reply-Message contains "Enter a new PIN having from 4 to 6 digits:"

- New-PIN-mode request confirmation PIN

Reply-Message contains "Please re-enter new PIN:"

- New-PIN-mode success

Reply-Message contains "PIN Accepted"

- Next-tokencode-mode start

Reply-Message contains "enter the new tokencode"